# How can I prevent a Hebbian learning algorithm from learning the exact same function for each of the output neurons?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Suppose that your have a neural net with 5 input neurons fully connected to 2 output neurons. The input sequence is constructed in such a way that there are two distinct input patterns that often appear (one more frequently than the other), while being completely random otherwise.

When applying Hebbian learning to train this network in an unsupervised way (with normalization of the weights to prevent them from increasing infinitely), won't the two output neurons have exactly the same response? Will they not both activate when seeing the most frequently appearing pattern?

What adaptations to the basic Hebbian learning algorithm are needed in order to prevent this? In an ideal scenario, one output neuron would learn to activate at the most frequently appearing pattern while the other only activates at the other one.

Comment: you can make the output layer to mutually inhibit each other

Comment: @Memming, can you elaborate or point me in the direction of some relevant papers?